# systemd unit file never finishes when using a shell command with pipes

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to execute a shell script with systemd.

If I run my script from the bash everything works fine. But if I run the same script via systemd it never finishes. The command where it seems to hang is:

```
random="$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w128 | head -n1)"
```

If I'm replacing this line with `random="1234"` it also runs with systemd. I guess the 'hanging' command is the `tr` - its process never finishes.

And this is the systemd unit file I'm using:

```
[Unit]
Description=my script

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/mypath/script.sh start
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /mypath/RUNNING_PID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does your service fork? If not, then `Type=fork` is wrong service type. See `man systemd.service` for options.

Comment: `Restart=on-failure` will restart it if systemd sees that the script exited with non zero status. Is `random="$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w128 | head -n1)"` the last command in the script?

Comment: @alvits Yes, I want to restart the service if it crashes. And: the tr is not the last command in the script.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Yes it forks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: Made the explanation clearer and added new information.

**Short answer**: `systemd` is filtering `SIGPIPE`s, so
set `IgnoreSIGPIPE=false` under `[Service]` in the `.service` file. From the `systemd.exec` manual:

> ```
>    IgnoreSIGPIPE=
>        Takes a boolean argument. If true, causes
>        SIGPIPE to be ignored in the executed process.
>        Defaults to true because SIGPIPE generally is
>        useful only in shell pipelines.
> ```

**Long explanation**:

> random="$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w128 |
> head -n1)"

When the `head` command exits after the first newline received from `fold`, its open file descriptors are closed.
Thus when the `fold` command later tries to write to the pipe, it will receive a `SIGPIPE` signal (as described in `pipe(7)`).
The default action for this signal is a termination of the process.
That mechanism repeats towards the start of the pipeline, so the `fold` command would be terminated next, and eventually the `tr` command.

However, when the pipeline is run under `systemd`, `systemd` sets the default action for `SIGPIPE` to `SIG_IGN`, which makes the processes in the pipeline ignore the signal.

When `fold` (and the other components of the pipeline) inherits that signal handler, it won't be notified (killed) via `SIGPIPE` when writing to the now closed output pipe (Instead each write to the pipe will return an `EPIPE` error).

As `fold` command does not check the return value of those `write` calls (at least not in `coreutils-8.26`), this makes `fold` continue reading from the pipe (stdin) and to write to the closed pipe (stdout), even though an error is reported each time.
So `fold` keeps its input pipe from `tr` open, and `tr` will happily write to the output pipe feeding `fold` forever.

Comment: This `Restart=on-failure` affects the behavior. You already figured out the exit status.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I looked up IgnoreSIGPIPE and it looks like it defaults to true: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#IgnoreSIGPIPE=. But what you wrote before - before you edited the answer - actually helped me :). If I use `$(LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom 2>/dev/null | dd bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null)` it works. I exchanged `fold -w128 | head -n1` with `dd bs=128 count=1` like you suggested before. And I had to add `2>/dev/null` to get rid of the `tr: write error: Broken pipe` that was in journalctl. So I'd check your answer as correct as it was before :)

Comment: Your original answer is a workaround. But this revised answer is definitely the answer. Thanks for quoting the man page, it helps everyone in the community.